# Generate SSL certificate for bip (IRC proxy) with Letsencrypt

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, irc, lets-encrypt

Letsencrypt is fantastic because it lets users generate valid (not self-signed) SSL certificates for free. I'm using [bip](https://bip.milkypond.org/) as an IRC proxy. Bip can use an SSL certificate for encryption, but [the documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/5/bip.conf) is a bit fuzzy on this.

I know how to generate certificates with letsencrypt. I guess I must concatenate some of the letsencrypt generated files, among `cert.pem`, `chain.pem`, fullchain.pem`and`privkey.pem` to get a valid bip certificate. But which ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking how to configure bip to use the Let's Encrypt certificate so that clients can connect to it via SSL, the documentation provides the following:

```
client_side_ssl (default: false)
  When true, clients will need to connect to BIP using SSL. You'll also need to
  generate a    SSL cert/key pair in <bipdir>/bip.pem (usually ~/.bip/bip.pem or
  /var/lib/bip/bip.pem) or <client_side_ssl_pem> if defined.

client_side_ssl_pem (default: <bipdir>/bip.pem)
  Set this to the full path of the cert/key pair bip should use to accept clients
  SSL connections
```

So from that I gather you will need to `cat privkey.pem cert.pem > bip.pem` and enable `client_side_ssl` and point `client_side_ssl_pem` to `bip.pem` if it's not in one of the specified locations.

I don't believe you'll need to add the CA chain as Let's Encrypt is a trusted CA and the clients should be able to reconstruct the chain themselves. If that's not the case, you can add `chain.pem` to `bip.pem` as well.

I also found a handy guide that might be of use here: https://flexion.org/posts/2014-04-bip-irc-proxy/

Comment: Great, it works! However, it *also* works when I replace `cert.pem` by `fullchain.pem`. If I understand correctly [the docs](http://letsencrypt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#where-are-my-certificates) it's better to use `fullchain.pem`, right?

Comment: Yes, `fullchain.pem` should contain all the necessary certificates, from leaf to root, and will allow clients to construct a complete chain of trust for your certificate.